# Speeding up Angular $compile function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, frontend

I'm manually compiling a template against a new scope:

```
var scope = _.assign($rootScope.$new(true), {
  foo: 1,
  bar: 2
})
var element = angular.element('<my-element foo="foo" bar="bar"></my-element>')
$compile(element)(scope)
element.appendTo(container)
```

After running a basic profile, the slowest part of this code is `$compile`, which takes ~1ms per compilation. I need to compile ~100 elements at a time, as the user scrolls.

There are a lot of optimizations I can apply to speed up compilations **after the 1st round of $compiles**, but I'd like to speed up the very 1st round of 100 compiles. I'd also like to keep the templates in Angularland, and avoid injecting raw HTML.

How?

**Edit:** Copy+pasting my comment from below here for visibility for anyone that sees this thread in the future:

Ok, it finally makes sense. If you pass in a function as a 2nd argument to $link, angular will clone the node for you. If you don't, it will reuse the same node on every call to $link. Either way, you can access the returned node both synchronously (as the return value of $link) and asynchronously (within your callback). This is a poorly designed API, I filed an issue in Angular's issue tracker here - github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11824

Comment: Do you want to compile or link 100 elements to scope as ng-repeat does?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the elements are of the same structure and only differ in the scope against which they are linked, then you should `$compile` the template *once* and then `link` each of the 100 elements against their respective scopes.

```
var myElement = angular.element('<my-element foo="foo" bar="bar"></my-element>');
var myElementLinkFn = $compile(myElement);


// "items" here is the data that drives the creation of myElement elements
angular.forEach(items, function(item){
   var newScope = $scope.$new(true);

   newScope.foo = item.foo;
   newScope.bar = item.bar;

   myElementLinkFn(newScope, function(clone){
      container.append(clone);
   })
});
```

Comment: I'm running into another perf issue: since the clone is returned asynchronously, the time it takes to append the clone to my container is highly variable. Is there a synchronous API to get the clone?

Comment: @bcherny, the `clone` is returned syncronously

Comment: ah, that's true. looking through the $compile code, it seems that one $compile call maps to one element - there's no way to generate multiple elements from a single call. multiple link calls to one element will all share the same element.

Comment: Ok, it finally makes sense. If you pass in a function as a 2nd argument to $link, angular will clone the node for you. If you don't, it will reuse the same  node on every call to $link. Either way, you can access the returned node both synchronously (as the return value of $link) and asynchronously (within your callback). This is a poorly designed API, I filed an issue in Angular's issue tracker here - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/11824

Comment: @bcherny, I think you are confusing something here. If you pass what's called a `cloneConnectFn`, this function will be given a clone of the node that was compiled. And you then free to attach that into the DOM, with something like `element.append(clone)`. The result of that link function is that same DOM element clone *after* it was linked. All of these are happening **synchronously**. If you pass a `cloneAttachFn`, then it generates a clone - otherwise, it links the node that you compiled. Here's a [**demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/92jyEUn0Drg085dhqxzh)