# What does it mean that angular compile is executed “only once” for ngRepeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I read a few blogs about compile and link in angular directives. A lot of people say that compile is executed only once for ngRepeat implementation. I checked it and I see that post link is executed also only once. I added break points in ngRepeatDirective in angular.js (v1.3.13) and I see that post link is also executed only once.

Can somebody explain me why people emphasize that compile is executed only once while post link is also executed only once.

Places where I added break points:

```
   ……
    compile: function ngRepeatCompile($element, $attr) {
      debugger;

  ……
     return function ngRepeatLink($scope, $element, $attr, ctrl, $transclude) {
        debugger;
   ……
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a directive that:

- has a `compile` function
- has a `link` function
- is repeated using `ng-repeat`

then:

- the `compile` function is called once
- the `link` function is called n times (number of repeats)

Here is a [working example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OUyGYNh1iVqXpafx4smE).

If you open the console in the example, you will see that the `compile` function is called once and the `link` function is called 4 times.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes in your example compile is called one time and link is called 4 times but you created your custom directive and I am asking about ng-repeat.
Another thing is that I still do not understand how it happens that in your example compile is called one time and link is called 4 times.

Comment: Maybe the „only once” for ngRepeat is valid only when in ngRepeat we use another custom directive?

Comment: @user2449394, what jvandemo and the blogs you read referred to was that any directive (custom or built-in) that is repeated with `ng-repeat` is compiled once and linked N times. It wasn't about the `ngRepeat` directive itself. I recently answered a question that could explain to you the importance of compiling-once: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29958723/speeding-up-angular-compile-function/29959195#29959195

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I get it. jvandemo thanks also for your blog and earlier help!